# Bin packing where each item must occur in $k$ bins

Tags: approximation-algorithms, optimization, packing

I am looking for information on a generalization of bin-packing in which each item should appear in exactly $k$ different bins, for some positive integer $k$. The standard bin packing problem corresponds to $k=1$. Obviously, the problem is at least as hard as bin packing; I am interested in whether approximation algorithms for bin packing provide good results for $k>1$.

At first glance, it seems we could reduce this variant to bin packing by having $k$ copies of each item (there is a recent algorithm for [bin packing with a constant number of item types](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3421750)). However, the problems are different: in my setting, an item cannot appear twice in the same bin.

As an example, suppose the items are x, y, z, all items have size 1, and the bin capacity is 2. With $k=1$, we need two bins, e.g. {x,y} and {z}. With $k=2$, we need three bins, {x,y} and {y,z} and {z,x}. But if we fill the first two bins with {x,y} and {x,y} then we must use two additional bins {z} and {z}, so we get a sub-optimal solution.

Is anything known about this problem?

<sup>Note: the problem is motivated by the practical [electricity packing](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/the-electricity-packing-problem) problem. A solution for the $k$-times-bin-packing problem implies a lower bound for the electricity packing problem. Though I am not sure of this lower bound is tight.</sup>

Comment: If $k$ is a fixed constant then the standard aymptotic FPTAS that yields a packing with $(1+\epsilon)OPT + 1$ appears to generalize. Have you tried it?

Comment: @ChandraChekuri Do you mean the algorithm by Hoberg and Rothvoss (2017), that finds a packing with OPT+log(OPT) bins?

Comment: The Asymptotic PTAS is due to de la Vega and Leuker. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02579456. Chapter 9 in Vazirani's book on approximation and Chapter 4 in Williamson-Shmoys book cover this material. OPT + log (OPT) is harder result than (1+\eps) OPT + 1.